# disable the array auto sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var mapObj  = {};

 var selectVal  = $(this).find('select').val(); // 3,2,6,1

 if (mapObj[selectVal]) {
     mapObj[selectVal] += Number($(this).find(".first").val());
 } else {
     mapObj[selectVal] = Number($(this).find(".first").val());
 }
```

Result will become

```
{1: 5, 2: 10, 3:5, 6:10}
```

The above code will auto sorting the data to me, but I want it to follow the data that I retrieve so it will become data as below. The data will be using a loop, so the number will get depend on user enter. How can I disable the sorting?

Should be

```
{3: 5, 2: 10, 6:10, 1:5}
```

Comment: You don't have an array, you have objects, and the ordering of property names when iterating through them is controlled by rules you cannot change. If you need to access property names in some particular order, keep the names separately in an array.

Comment: @Pointy, any example for this ya?

Comment: Object.keys(obj).sort().map(...)

Comment: An object with numeric keys will always get shown in sorted order

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your variable mapObj an array instead of an object. The order is not an issue for array elements like so: `[{3: 5}, {2: 10}, {6: 10}, {1: 5}]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add + before each key for example

```js
let obj1 = {3: 5, 2: 1, 1: 5};
let obj2 = {'+3': 5, '+2': 1, '+1': 5};

$('#obj1').html(JSON.stringify(obj1));
$('#obj2').html(JSON.stringify(obj2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="obj1"></div>
<div id="obj2"></div>
```

I added working example please check